# How do I close window(s) in MAC without re-opening the window

Tags: macos, mojave

How do I close windows from dock or anywhere else without needing to open the window each time just to close it

If I have 10 windows opened(of the same application) and want to **selectively** close 7 of them belonging to the **same** app, is it possible to close them(without needing to re-opening those windows) by right clicking the app icon in the dock/mission control/App Expose/etc and then closing the ones I don't need? (I also have windows of other apps opened and I don't to want to navigate through them)

Re-Opening each window and then clicking the close button(or a keyboard shortcut) seems to be too much work. Looks like a useful feature that is missing in MAC

Comment: Are you talking in context of specific app(s) or in general?

Comment: General question. When I open 10 windows of the same application. If each window belongs to separate app then I can easily close those windows from the dock because I will have 10 different app icons in the dock. So I don't need to open the window to close it

Comment: What is the point of opening a window just to close it when I can do that from dock or somewhere else if possible

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33414/how-to-make-the-mac-os-x-finder-suck-less/

Comment: It would have been nice if atleast "App Expose" feature had a close button to close the window

Answer (score 2):

No, what you're asking is not natively possible.

In other words, an application's Dock Tile menu does not natively allow for closing individual windows the app has open.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the update. Looks like a useful feature that is missing in MAC. I would need to repeat the same action multiple times to close each window then

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the fastest way to close several document windows within an application, then there are already plenty of better ways than using the Dock might provide.

You can cycle through open windows in one app with `` Command ` `` (this might vary in other keyboard layouts, but it's usually the key to the left of Z). You can close several documents in one application with a succession of `Command W`, using `` Command ` `` to flick past documents you want to keep open. I'd say that's much quicker than trying to close 7 of 10 in the Dock. If you get a prompt to **Save** or **Don't Save**, you can use `Command S` or `Command D`.

You can use the **Application Windows** function key to show all the windows of an application. Also **Mission Control** shows you all the windows of all apps.

You can close all documents of one app with `Alt Command W`, or by alt-clicking on any window's red dot.

You can also Minimize windows into the Dock, but I would advise against it. It's very easy to forget about what you've minimized, and you have to un-minimize before you can do anything else with the window. You can't use the window cycling shortcut above to access minimized windows.

Comment: Mission control and `Alt Command W` are not useful int this case because anyhave I have to open each window and then close it because I want to close only few of those windows but not all of them



........................ "with a succession of Command W, using Command ` to flick past documents you want to keep open" --can you elaborate. I am not able to do this

Comment: You can't use Command W to close a window? Or the shortcut to cycle through documents windows doesn't work? What keyboard language do you have?

Comment: Hi benwiggy, I am new to MAC. I tried Command+W and looks like it is looping through all the windows and not just the windows of the single app(also it is loosing focus of the window sometimes and I had to manually click on a window before continuing with the command+W). I have 10 windows of single app and another 8 windows belonging to 8 different apps. I now want to concentrate on the 10 windows belonging to the single app only and not go through all my other open windows just for the sake of closing those windows

Comment: That's strange. Command W should close one document window and bring the next window of that application to the front. Command W should not cause a switch to another app. What MacOS version do you have?

Comment: Hi, how is command+W relevant to this question. I am using MacOS High Sierra 10.13 and command+` does not do anything on my machine. Looks like MAC OS does not have any feature to solve this problem

Comment: You are trying to close windows quickly, are you not? Command W closes a window and brings the next document up. Please answer my question about what keyboard layout you use, which may explain why the Command ` doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yes I am trying to close windows quickly but also "selectively" i.e only close the windows that I don't need. using command+W I have to close all the windows one by one to navigate to the next window. When I right click the app icon in the dock (or in mission control) then I can see a complete list of all the windows of that particular app(but no x icon to close). Now I want to "selectively" close some of those windows without needing to open each one. I have QWERTY keyboard, not sure if that answers the question

Comment: Third time: Please answer my question about what keyboard layout you use, which may explain why the Command ` doesn't work for you.

Comment: No:  US, French, Swedish, Brazilian.....

Comment: Netherlands keyboard

Comment: System PReferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard panel should show you what the shortcut for Moving focus to the next window. Once you have this, you can bypass the documents you want to keep and then close the ones you want to close. Hold down Command and press one of two buttons to close or keep. That is as easy as choosing a window to close could possibly be.

Comment: It shows command+Backquote but it is not working. I have no idea why

Comment: I updated to Mojave OS and now the command+Backquote is working. Not exactly what I want(because I don't want to open each window be it keyboard shortcut or using the mouse), but this is the best possible thing right now in MAC OS. Thanks